# WYSIWYG way to work with xyz.tpl.php/CSS files?

Tags: php, css, task-parallel-library

I recently purchased a script that I'm trying to change the CSS to pimp it up :)

However since I'm fairly new to CSS/PHP (I've done ASP before), I'm trying to use the "Live view" feature Dreamweaver 5.5 to edit the tpl.php files. I have setup the site as instructed in DW and it's working with basic PHP files, however when I try to open a tpl.php file it doesnt seem to handle all the includes or something, so essentially it doesnt know how to retrieve all the related CSS etc in order to show me what the site looks like.

It has the following code structure:

1. www.xyz.com -> this calls the index.php
2. Within index.php, it calls `include_once ('global_mainpage.php');`
3. Within global_mainpage.php it then calls `$template_output .= $template->process('mainpage.tpl.php');`
4. mainpage.tpl.php is the file that I need to change the layouts/CSS class reference etc.

My ideal way to work with the site is:

1. Say if I want to change something on index.php
2. I just click on one of the elements in live view
3. It would automatically launch the tpl.php file being used
4. I can then examine the CSS used and make a change to it
5. hit save and be able to view the change I just made

If this is not possible, do I have no choice but to use Aptana? I've used it before editing PHP code, but not tpl.php - I was hoping to have a WYSIWYG editor for tpl.php...

Many thanks for your help gurus! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use [FireBug](http://www.getfirebug.com) on Firefox and hook it up with [cssUpdater](http://www.cssupdater.com)?

Comment: Thanks Moin Zaman, but would this firebug+cssupdater+firefox setup provide me with a WYSIWYG experience though? ie. I can drag/adjust elements on the page? And would it work if I need to work with tpl.php  files re. layouts?

Comment: Dreamweaver's live view or design view are nowhere near as accurate as you'd like them to be. I wouldn't push it to be able to do layout with drag and drop. Another program that's creating a stir is Adobe's muse.adobe.com but thats just for static websites, not PHP

Comment: ok, thanks Moin! I would probably try hooking up aptana with my dev server and do debug from there....